# Postfix installation

Tags: postfix

I'm trying to install Postfix as per Ubuntu's instructions, but during the installation process, I'm getting a purple configuration page with various options listed (no config/internet site etc), but there is nowhere to select or type what installation I require. The terminal doesn't repsond to anything other than shutting it down.

Am I missing something simple here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I've seen such things, I select the option I want with the up and down arrows. Then I use the Tab key until the "OK" button is highlighted. Then press Enter.

I can see this isn't obvious if you're not used to terminal conventions.